# touchCount difficulty on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

This could be because I've been testing on a UnityRemote, however I'm trying to restart my main scene by touching with more than one finger on an android. `endCondition` is a variable I set as active when the player has been destroyed. Here is what my code looks like. All I want to do is restart the scene with multi-touch. Neither of the prints logged to the console so I doubt the multiple touches are being recognized. Here is my code that is inside of `Update()`

```
if (endCondition && (Input.touchCount > 1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch(i);
            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                print("Made it here");
            }
            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                print("Made it here");
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: endCondition  is probably false. Check it with Debug.Log and make sure that it is true.

Comment: just tested this by taking out `endCondition` and no luck

Comment: How about `Input.touchCount > 0` ?

Comment: @Programmer it works then, with only one touch. any idea what that is?

Comment: I don't know why but look at my answer. That's the way you should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
if (endCondition)
        {
            int fingersAmount = Input.touchCount;

            //1 FINGER
            if (fingersAmount == 1)
            {

                Touch t = Input.GetTouch(fingersAmount - 1);
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    Debug.Log("ONE FINGER");
                }
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    Debug.Log("ONE FINGER END");
                    //SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");

                }
            }

            //2 FINGERS
            else if (fingersAmount == 2)
            {

                Touch t = Input.GetTouch(fingersAmount - 1);
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    Debug.Log("TWO FINGERS");
                }
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    Debug.Log("TWO FINGERS END");
                    //SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");

                }
            }
            //3 FINGERS
            else if (fingersAmount == 3)
            {

                Touch t = Input.GetTouch(fingersAmount - 1);
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    Debug.Log("THREE FINGERS");
                }
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    Debug.Log("THREE FINGERS END");
                    //SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are welcome, You can always extend it to add more fingers if you want. Good luck.